# django "Field 'id' expected a number but got 'yoavlv'."

Tags: django

I want to create a page where the user can see the details he posted on the site. The problem I get "Field 'id' expected a number but got 'yoavlv'." I already searched for solution and try to solve it with "slug" but it didn't work..

```
def my_items(request, user):
user_items = get_object_or_404(Add_Item, user=user)
items = Add_Item.objects.filter(user =user_items)
return render(request, 'my_items.html',{"items":items,})
```

model :

```
class Add_Item(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True)
title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
categories  = models.CharField(max_length=255 , choices=all_categories)
description = RichTextField(blank=True,null=True)
condition = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=cond)
city = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=cy.city, blank=True)
street = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
home_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
header_img = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='img/')
more_img = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='img/')
Pub_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Is `user` perhaps the username, and not the User object? If so, you could change the first line to something like `user_items = get_object_or_404(Add_Item, user=get_object_or_404(User, username=user))`

Comment: The user is the ForeignKey in Add_Item...